# How can I write a PostgreSQL and Python command from cleaning this original table to result table as shown below?

Tags: postgresql, data-cleaning, cross-join

[image: Original table]

[image: Result table]

In PostgreSQL, I tried the function `trim(unnest(string_to_array` to clean and distribute to rows but it will not distribute each value to each other (user_id and dates).

Comment: Could you please share your question in plain text instead of an image somewhere else?

Comment: What data type is the column `dates`? Looks like `jsonb` or `json`

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `dates` is defined as `jsonb` and `user_id` is defined as `int[]` you can do something like this:

```
select u.user_id, 
       d.dates,
       t."type", 
       t.time_start, 
       t.time_end
from the_table t
  cross join unnest(t.user_id) as u(user_id)
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(t.dates) as d(dates)
order by u.user_id, d.date
```

If `dates` is not a `jsonb` column, you need to cast it: `jsonb_array_elements_text(t.dates::jsonb)`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/kRhOUhv8)